# resize borderless form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize, borderless

I am able to resize the from using the code below but it resizes towards right side , from bottom right corner

i want to modify the code so that user can re size the form from bottom left corner.

also most of the solution given on this site are based on  WndProc / WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN and i am not using it because my form have lots of controls so it flicker's very badly.

```
  Private Shared frmLastWidth As Integer = 0
  Private Shared frmLastHeight As Integer = 0
  Private Shared frmWidth As Integer
  Private Shared frmHeight As Integer
  Private Shared frmIsResizing As Boolean = False
  Private frmRectangle As New System.Drawing.Rectangle()

  Private Sub ResizeMe_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ResizeMe.MouseUp
    If frmIsResizing Then


      frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left, Me.Top)



      frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmWidth, frmHeight)
      ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)
      Me.Width = frmWidth
      Me.Height = frmHeight
      frmIsResizing = False

    End If





  End Sub

  Private Sub ResizeMe_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ResizeMe.MouseDown

    frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left, Me.Top)
    frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmWidth, frmHeight)
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)

  End Sub



  Private Sub ResizeMe_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ResizeMe.MouseMove




    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

 'Me.ResizeRedraw = false
    Dim sizeageX As Integer = MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X
    Dim sizeageY As Integer = MousePosition.Y - Me.Location.Y

    ' Use this to restrict Width
    If sizeageX < Me.MinimumSize.Width Then
      sizeageX = Me.MinimumSize.Width
    End If
    ' Use this to restrict Height
    If sizeageY < Me.MinimumSize.Height Then
      sizeageY = Me.MinimumSize.Height
    End If
    frmWidth = sizeageX
    frmHeight = sizeageY

    If frmLastWidth = 0 Then
      frmLastWidth = frmWidth
    End If
    If frmLastHeight = 0 Then
      frmLastHeight = frmHeight
    End If
    If frmIsResizing Then

      frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left, Me.Top)
      frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmLastWidth, frmLastHeight)
    End If

    frmIsResizing = True

    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)
    frmLastWidth = frmWidth
    frmLastHeight = frmHeight


    frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left, Me.Top)
    frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmWidth, frmHeight)
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)
  End Sub

  Private Sub ResizeRight(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    'Me.ResizeRedraw = false

    Dim sizeageX As Integer = (MousePosition.X + Me.Width) - Me.Location.X
    Dim sizeageY As Integer = (MousePosition.Y + Me.Height) - Me.Location.Y



    ' Use this to restrict Width
    If sizeageX < Me.MinimumSize.Width Then
      sizeageX = Me.MinimumSize.Width
    End If
    ' Use this to restrict Height
    If sizeageY < Me.MinimumSize.Height Then
      sizeageY = Me.MinimumSize.Height
    End If
    frmWidth = sizeageX
    frmHeight = sizeageY

    If frmLastWidth = 0 Then
      frmLastWidth = frmWidth
    End If
    If frmLastHeight = 0 Then
      frmLastHeight = frmHeight
    End If
    If frmIsResizing Then

      frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left, Me.Top)
      frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmLastWidth, frmLastHeight)
    End If

    frmIsResizing = True

    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)
    frmLastWidth = frmWidth
    frmLastHeight = frmHeight


    frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left, Me.Top)
    frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmWidth, frmHeight)
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)


    End If


  End Sub
```

**Update**

i was able to re size the form bottom left corner but it shows the dashed lines many times also the dashed lines does not restrict to minimum height and width of the form the modified code is

```
 Private Sub ResizeRight(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    'Me.ResizeRedraw = false
    Dim sizeageX As Integer = MousePosition.X + Me.Location.X
    Dim sizeageY As Integer = MousePosition.Y + Me.Location.Y

    ' Use this to restrict Width
    If sizeageX > Me.MinimumSize.Width Then
      sizeageX = Me.MinimumSize.Width
    End If
    ' Use this to restrict Height
    If sizeageY > Me.MinimumSize.Height Then
      sizeageY = Me.MinimumSize.Height
    End If
    frmWidth = sizeageX - e.X
    frmHeight = sizeageY - e.Y


    If frmLastWidth = 0 Then
      frmLastWidth = frmWidth
    End If
    If frmLastHeight = 0 Then
      frmLastHeight = frmHeight
    End If

    If frmIsResizing Then

      frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left + e.X, Me.Top)
      frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmLastWidth, frmLastHeight)
    End If

    frmIsResizing = True

    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, System.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)
    frmLastWidth = frmWidth
    frmLastHeight = frmHeight


    frmRectangle.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Left + e.X, Me.Top)
    frmRectangle.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(frmWidth, frmHeight)
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(frmRectangle, Color.Black, system.Windows.Forms.FrameStyle.Dashed)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is suspend the Control Layout (Suspend.Layout) according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout%28VS.80%29.aspx
That might be able to stop the flickering.